# Is there a way to convert a JUnit Test into a SIDE file?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit, junit5, selenium-ide

I'm new to using Selenium and I was wondering if there's a way to convert a JUnit test into a SIDE file to use in Selenium IDE. I know how to export SIDE files into JUnit but I was wondering if there's a way to convert the JUnit file back into a SIDE file after improving the tests with JUNIT. Thanks in advance!

I don't see any options for importing Junit files in the Selenium IDE

Comment: Adding an example of what unit test you'd like to be converted into what file would be helpful.